# Is PSN card country locked in Europe?

Tags: psn

I created a PSN account in one country in Europe and I was able to buy PSN cards there and load credits on my account. 
However, now I live in a different European country and I wonder if locally bought PSN cards are valid for my account. User experience reports seems to vary a lot and I can’t find a definitive answer (and I don’t like the idea to waste my money trying myself). The two countries are using the same currency (i.e. Euro)

Comment: This sounds like a question that could be best answered by asking Sony. I believe they have live chat available on their support page.

Comment: You might want to add the specific countries to the question. Otherwise you are likely to get the same varying user experience reports that you found in your research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it`s not been changed after the release of the PS4. The PlayStation network cards are country specific if not i all cases then in most. It does not matter if the currency is the same it is still locked to that specific area. Look at the the flag in top left corner.

http://uk.playstation.com/pscards/